# Store/Import variables & functions Processing(JS)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, processing, processing.js

Stack Overflow! I wanted to store variables in another file so that I would load the variables in file 1, and draw the scene in file 2, ex.

**closet.js**
`var message = "Hello there";`

**drawer.js**
`draw = function() { text(message, 100, 100); };`

So I would do something like that, but instead of importing the files like this;

`<canvas data-processing-sources="closet.js drawer.js"></canvas>`

I wanted to be able to include them **in** file 2, sort of like this;

**closet.js**
`var message = "Hello there";`

**drawer.js**
`import("closet.js");
draw = function() {
  text(message, 100, 100);
};`

Is there a way to do this without including them in the HTML file itself?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file), which yours might even be a duplicate of. It lists several ways to do this in JavaScript, including using JQuery or dynamically adding the `<script>` tags to the `<head>` of your page.

But if you're using the Processing editor, you have another option: use **classes** by creating a **new tab** in the Processing editor. For all your purposes, you can treat this as a separate file. So lets say you created a separate `Closet` tab with a `message` variable. Your main sketch code might look like this:

```
Closet c = new Closet();
draw = function() {
  text(c.message, 100, 100);
};
```

I think this is probably the way to go. It seems like you're trying to over-engineer a solution: either include the files in the html (this is what 99% of all JavaScript code does) or use a class (this is what 99% of all Processing code does).

Comment: Oki, thanks again Kevin. You really must be a busy man! I see you everywhere on this site :)! Thanks for helping out the entire StackOverflow community :)